# Can't Upload Image via AJAX with Additional Parameters Because processData: false

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel

I am trying to upload an image using ajax using the following code:

```
function saveToServer(file) {

    const fd = new FormData();
    fd.append('image', file);

    $.ajax({
        method: 'post',
        data: {
            image: fd,
            diaryHash: "{{ $diary->hash }}",
            entryHash: "{{ $entry->hash }}",
        },
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        url: "{{ action('EntriesController@storeImage') }}",
        success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
            const url = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText).data;
            insertToEditor(url);
        }
    });
}
```

I am passing the image to be stored and I am passing two other variables, `diaryHash` and `entryHash`.

I am not getting my passed variables in my controller because `processData` is set to `false`.

**How do I pass data along with an image when doing an image upload with AJAX?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue is because you're placing the FormData object in the object to be serialised. You need to invert that logic and place the additional parameter *inside* the FormData, like this:

```
function saveToServer(file) {   
  const fd = new FormData();
  fd.append('image', file);
  fd.append('diaryHash', '{{ $diary->hash }}');
  fd.append('entryHash', '{{ $entry->hash }}');

  $.ajax({
    method: 'post',
    data: fd,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    dataType: 'json',
    url: "{{ action('EntriesController@storeImage') }}",
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
      const url = data.data;
      insertToEditor(url);
    }
  });
}
```

Also note that I added the `dataType` property to the request so that jQuery will automatically deserialise the response for you.